# TMapView.AddPolyline crashes the app

Tags: c++builder-xe8

Hello i am trying to create an application to test the map capabilities of the TMapView component. So I am trying this code to add some polylines on the map surface:

```
TArray__1<TMapCoordinate> mapCoords;
mapCoords.Length = 2;
mapCoords[0].Latitude = 0.1;
mapCoords[0].Longitude = 0.1;
mapCoords[1].Latitude = 0.5;
mapCoords[1].Longitude = 0.5;
TMapPolylineDescriptor mapDesc = TMapPolylineDescriptor::Create(mapCoords);
MapView1->AddPolyline(mapDesc);
MapView1->Location = mapCoords[0];
```

I have no idea why the code crashes the app. I can't debug the app because I am working on a virtual machine(I am not allowed to install 3rd party apps on the specific laptop) and the virtual machine doesn't recognize my phone. Please help me out.

Comment: If you cannot use the debugger (not even the remote debugger?), then you will have to add some logging and try/catch blocks to the code, or add an exception logger like MadExcept or EurekaLog to your project, so you can isolate the particular line that is crashing.  Offhand, I don't see anything wrong with the code you have shown, so maybe `TMapView` simply has a bug when running on your particular phone.

Comment: As for the VM communicating with the phone, at least for Android, you can connect the phone to the Host via USB and use a tunnel (like SSH) to connect the VM's ADB (Android Debugger Bridge) to the Host's ADB, then the IDE can communicate with the phone as if it were a local device. See [Debugging Against a Remote Android Emulator](http://delphi.org/2013/09/debugging-against-a-remote-android-emulator/),  This does mean the Android SDK has to be installed on the Host, though.  I don't know if there is an equivalent technique for iOS.

Comment: Well i feel a bit embarrassed about this but i guess it was my mistake. I was using this code in the constructor of the form and for some reason in the constructor it was calling some kind of cleanup code on the TMapView and this is where the error was occuring(i've tried the code in my other machine where i could debug the app). So, i've moved the code to a button and it worked as it should. Thanks a lot for the help :)